# Where to get various ERC20 token for Goerli and sepolia testnets

Tags: uniswap, goerli, aave, sepolia, faucets

I'm trying to get a collection of erc20 tokens (weth, usdc, dai, wbtc) in a testnet either sepolia or goerli

Answer (score 2):

In my attempt to develop in Dapp I went on the hunt for *faucets* and here is the few ressources I found that is currently working

For goerli:

- I got goerliETH from [faucet.chainstack.com](https://faucet.chainstack.com/goerli-testnet-faucet) (The destination wallet need to have at least 0.006 eth on the main net)
- Swapped my goerliETH for some WETH, WBTC, DAI, USDC using [uniswap](https://app.uniswap.org/swap) (I just used their webapp portable while my metamask wallet WAS connected to Goerli)

For Sepolia:

- I got my sepoliaETH from [sepoliafaucet.com](https://sepoliafaucet.com/)
- got some WBTC, ect from [aave](https://staging.aave.com/faucet/) (still need some sepoliaETH to pay the gas fee)
- uniswap was not working (no one provided liquidity to the pool yet?)

---

Answer (score 0):

In testnets you can just mine directly and get ethers that way. Testnets have much lower difficulty compared to mainnet.